# iOS5 - how to use storyboard to transit from UITableViewController to another ViewController

Tags: ios5, storyboard

Using Storyboard I want to transition from UITableViewController to another ViewController on the click of Detail Disclosure button. I created a proper segue, but the transition does not happen when I run the application. Creating a segue from UIButton to a ViewController works properly. I tried embedding Navigation Controller in UITableViewController, it did not help.

Look forward to somebody helping me with this, as I have already spent four days on it.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used StoryBoard yet, but you should check out this tutorial on it.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Answer (score 4):

Here's the most complete example I have found. Most have fallen short by not providing an example of how to go from the list of records to the detail of the selected records.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007416-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

and here's the link to part 2 of the above tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2

Answer (score 0):

It should work without any code on your side
Ctrl click the prototype cell (table cell) and drag it to connect with the detail view. This will pop up a segue window. I chose Push since I have a navigation controller - but you can use Modal as well.
Note the segue name should show "Segue from UITableViewCell to ).
I've put in the disclosure icon on the Table cell as well.

Comment: I solved it by reading raywenderlich's tutorial suggested in the previous comment. I had to look up part-2 of the tutorial, the link to which is available on raywenderlich's tweet. The solution required the coding of didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. I would love to know if there is a solution without coding (as in the case of UIButton Segue).

Comment: It's not possible without code, in the case of a tap on a Detail Disclosure button in a table view cell.